# Upgraded postgresql in local Rails 4 app and now FATAL: database "[myapp]_development" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I've gotten stuck trying to upgrade an old rails 4.0.13 app.

It's currently running on Heroku's cedar-14 stack and I'm trying to upgrade to the heroku-18 stack.  The earliest version of ruby that Heroku-18 accepts is 2.3.8 so I started there.  Locally I changed the Gemfile to ruby 2.3.8 and ran

```
$ bundle update --conservative
```

I got some warnings but nothing fatal.  When I tried to start the local postgresql database I got:

```
The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 9.5, 
which is not compatible with this version 9.6.1
```

I followed the great instructions at [How to upgrade PostgreSQL 9.5.5 to 9.6.1 using Homebrew (macOS).](https://gist.github.com/giannisp/b53a76047b07751ed3ade3c1db1d2c51) by [Ioannis Poulakas](https://www.ioannispoulakas.com) which was super useful.  The only change I made was his line 25:

His original command is:

```
$ pg_upgrade -b /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql95/9.5.5/bin -B /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.1/bin -d /usr/local/var/postgres95 -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

I modified that slightly for the files home-brew created on my local mac to:

```
$ pg_upgrade -b /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.5/9.5.14/bin -B /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.1/bin -d /usr/local/var/postgresql@9.5 -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

The consistency checks and upgrade worked but when I started the database again with:

```
$ pg_ctl start -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

I get `FATAL:  database "[myapp]_development" does not exist`

Anyone have any thoughts?  I'm reluctant to do something like `$ rake:db:create` for fear it would erase the data I just backed-up.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to download a snapshot of your database by following the instructions at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups.  Once you have downloaded a snapshot, restoring the database doing a direct database-to-database copy should be trivial.

At that point, I'd just run through the normal database recreation steps you mentioned, knowing you have a local snapshot if anything goes wrong and you lose your data for some reason.  If the database already exists, it would skip recreating anyway, so you actually may need to do a fresh drop/create/migrate anyway to fully fix your upgrade issue.

Comment: Thanks for your insight and link, @Submersed, but copying the heroku production database locally won't help me keep the different development data I've got on my local machine.  I think I'm going to try backup the production data on heroku and locally and then.... Somehow get local app to access data created with the older version of PostgreSQL